# Error when create a new Calculator on Spree Commerce gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I am learning rails and I like to learn by practicing trying to create something real.

I'm having some problems trying to create a new calculator to be used in the shipping area of ​​spree commerce.

Following this documentation tutorial.

http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/calculators.html#creating-a-new-calculator

Following the tutorial i created this class in this directory.

```
app/models/spree/calculator/shipping/my_own_calculator.rb
```

My class is this way

```
class MyOwnCalculator < Spree::ShippingCalculator
  def self.description
    Spree.t(:shipping_flat_rate_per_order)
  end

  def compute_package(package)
    self.preferred_amount
  end

  def available?(object)
    object.currency == "USD"
  end
end
```

and my file `config/initializers/spree.rb`

```
# Configure Spree Preferences
#
# Note: Initializing preferences available within the Admin will overwrite any changes that were made through the user interface when you restart.
#       If you would like users to be able to update a setting with the Admin it should NOT be set here.
#
# Note: If a preference is set here it will be stored within the cache & database upon initialization.
#       Just removing an entry from this initializer will not make the preference value go away.
#       Instead you must either set a new value or remove entry, clear cache, and remove database entry.
#
# In order to initialize a setting do:
# config.setting_name = 'new value'
Spree.config do |config|
  # Example:
  # Uncomment to stop tracking inventory levels in the application
  # config.track_inventory_levels = false
end

Spree.user_class = "Spree::User"

config = Rails.application.config
config.spree.calculators.shipping_methods << Spree::Calculator::Shipping::MyOwnCalculator
```

the error is this:

```
Unable to autoload constant Spree::Calculator::Shipping::MyOwnCalculator, expected /home/davi/dev/attsalaoruby/app/models/spree/calculator/shipping/my_own_calculator.rb to define it (LoadError)
```

and my stack trace is this way

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@5.0.0.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:512:in `load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload constant Spree::Calculator::Shipping::MyOwnCalculator, expected /home/davi/dev/attsalaoruby/app/models/spree/calculator/shipping/my_own_calculator.rb to define it (LoadError)
    from /home/davi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@5.0.0.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `const_missing'
    from /home/davi/dev/attsalaoruby/config/initializers/spree.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/davi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@5.0.0.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /home/davi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@5.0.0.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /home/davi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@5.0.0.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/davi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@5.0.0.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /home/davi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@5.0.0.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from /home/davi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@5.0.0.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
    from /home/davi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@5.0.0.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
    from /home/davi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@5.0.0.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/davi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@5.0.0.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
    from /home/davi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@5.0.0.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/davi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@5.0.0.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/davi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@5.0.0.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/davi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@5.0.0.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/davi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/davi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you defined your class inside module like this:

`module Spree
 module Calculator::Shipping
   class MyOwnCalculator < Spree::ShippingCalculator
    ...
   end
  end
end`

Comment: thanks for the help, i try change to your code but now  error is this

```Calculator is not a module (TypeError)```

Comment: I'm sorry, Spree already defined Calculator as a class. I edited the answer.

Comment: thanks one more time, i tryed to change the code and now the error is this 

``` undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) ```

Comment: config/initializers/spree.rb:21:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) the stack trace is like the class return nill now =/

Comment: What is the code in line 21? Could you please post the whole content of spree.rb?

Comment: i edit my post with the whole content of spree.rb

and line 21 is 

`config.spree.calculators.shipping_methods << Spree::Calculator::Shipping::MyOwnCalculator`

Comment: "config.spree.calculators.shipping_methods" is nil in by the time you use it. May be the tutorial is out of date. Look at the code of spree (https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/core/engine.rb), I think calculator should be registered with initializer "spree.register.calculators" as in this gist (https://gist.github.com/wrburgess/4600383)